# How to shutdown ThreadPoolExecutor in spring bean when tomcat is shutdown?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, shutdown

I create a threadpoolexecutor in a spring bean, so I need to shutdown this executor when tomcat is shutdown.

```
     public class PersistBO implements InitializingBean {

private ThreadPoolExecutor executer;

public void shutdownExecutor() {
    executer.shutdown();
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueLength);
    executer = new ThreadPoolExecutor(minThread, maxThread, threadKeepAliveTime, 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, taskQueue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());
}
```

I have searched solution on google and get a result. That is to add a shutdownhook to java.lang.runtime. However, the java docs says  java.lang.Runtime#shutdownHook is called when the last non-daemon thread exits. So it is a dead lock.  Is there any solution to shutdown executor in spring bean?

Comment: Your pool can also use deamon threads, if you provide it with right thread factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess lifecycle of the executor should depend on lifecycle of your application, not Tomcat as a whole. You can stop your application while Tomcat is still running, therefore `Runtime.shutdownHook()` is not applicable.

Since you already use Spring and its `InitializingBean` for initialization, you can use [`DispasableBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html) to perform cleanup when application context is being closed:

```
public class PersistBO implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean { 
    public void destroy() {
        shutdownExecutor();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Runtime` to add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). Here's a very good tutorial by Heinz Kabutz: http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/hooking%20_into_the_shutdown_call.shtml

Comment: but the java docs says java.lang.Runtime#shutdownHook is called when the last non-daemon thread exits. Will it is a dead lock?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to be notified when your application is being shutdown and shutdown the pool from the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Predestroy annotation on your shutdown method on the bean. this will result in spring calling this method when context is shutting down

Check if there is  some executor service has a thread running in background. you can shutdown an executor by calling `executor.shutdownNow()`.

also see http://taranmeet.com/jvm-not-shutting-down-on-spring-context-close/

Answer (score 0):

Here is  how to start and stop a thread in Spring bean.

```
    @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  BasicThreadFactory factory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
        .namingPattern("myspringbean-thread-%d").build();
  executorService =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
  executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     // do something
     System.out.println("thread started");
    } catch (Exception e) {
     logger.error("error: ", e);
    }

   }
  });
  executorService.shutdown();
 }


 @PreDestroy
 public void beandestroy() {
  if(executorService != null){
   executorService.shutdownNow();
  }
 }
```